# how do i access the required data using map and key

Tags: javascript, mongodb, reactjs

I have two names in the database and i want to display only the second name from it.If i give index=0 or index=1 it is giving me only the first name.So please tell me how do i retrieve the second name. And also it is retrieving the data from the database and displays it as separate un-ordered list. But i want to display all lists inside one un-ordered list.

```
   {this.state.post.map(function(item, index) {
     return (
    <ul key={index}>
    <li><Link className="prelink"  to="/namess">{item.Name}</Link>

    </ul>
```

JSON data

```
[ { _id: 5891ccdf0b50a85887a69ead,
    Id: 76,
    Age: 24,
    Name: ' SURYA',
    },
  { _id: 5892c76deebf7423e42da03b,
    Id: 77,
    Age: 24,
    Name: ' Vijay',
     } ]
```

Comment: would you post the Json of this.state.post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the second Name from JSON data as follows

```js
var data = [ { _id: '5891ccdf0b50a85887a69ead',
        Id: 76,
        Age: 24,
        Name: 'SURYA',
        },
      { _id: '5892c76deebf7423e42da03b',
        Id: 77,
        Age: 24,
        Name: ' Vijay',
     } ]

console.log(data[1].Name);
```

Also if you want to display everything as one unordered list instread of separate for each one, you nee to place the `<ul>` tag outside the map function like

```
 <ul>{this.state.post.map(function(item, index) {
     return (
        <li key={index}><Link className="prelink"  to="/namess">{item.Name}</Link></li>
     )
     })
  }</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks the ul part is working fine. But what i am asking is inside the link {item.Name} here i am accessing the json data from the database. This is where i need to retrieve the second data i.e Vijay.

Comment: @AbhilashMuttalli The think is you are mapping over the data and hence `item` will contain one object at a time, so in the second run of the map you will be able to retrieve the Name vishal. What is your exact usecase. Maybe you wont even need map